# a cron job using Quartz scheduler at 4:00 pm and 6:15 pm every day?

Tags: cron, expression

I want to run a cron job using Quartz scheduler at 4:00 pm and 6:15 pm every day .Can we combine these two in single cron expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
0 00,15 16,18 * * ?
```